# Save QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, xml, regex, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I would like to be able to save the QNetworkReply to a QString/QByteArray. In the examples I've seen they always saves the stream to another file.

At the moment my code looks something like this, where I get a string from the host and all I want to do is to parse it to look for the specified error code.

```
if(_reply->error() == QNetworkReply::UnknownContentError) {

    qDebug() << _reply->readAll(); // prints out the xml message

    QString test = QString(_reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << test; // ""

    QByteArray test2 = QByteArray(_reply->readAll());
    qDebug() << test2; // ""

    QRegExp rxlen("(<code>)(.*(?=</code>))");
    rxlen.setMinimal(true);

    int pos = rxlen.indexIn(test); // pos == -1

    if(pos > -1) {
        qDebug() << rxlen.cap(2); // never hit
    }

}
```

The message is pretty small and looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <error>
      <code>string-value</code>
      <message>string-value</message>
   </error>
```

So how can I load this small stream into memory, or just look for the error code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QNetworkReply inherits from QIODevice which is a stream. After you have read something from a stream it's not there anymore. After your debug line (one with `// prints out the xml message` comment) there's nothing to read anymore.

Comment: More specifically, it is a sequential-access `QIODevice` which results in the "read-once-and-then-it-is-gone" behavior. You can read more in the Detailed Description of [QNetworkReply](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html).